# Split text by Xpath.C# HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a HtmlNode with InnerHtml:

```
<a>SomeText</a>
DividerText:
<br>
TextToSelect1
<br/>
TextToSelect2
<br/>
TextToSelect3
<br>
TextToSelect4
```

It is possible to select all 'TextToSelect' only by XPath without c# Split or Regex?

like this: `/text()/substring-after('DividerText:')`

Or How can i get InnerHtml that excludes  tag a?

Comment: @tnw: Erm, he specifically says *without c# Split or Regex*

Comment: @tnw He said without RegEx

Comment: What's the discriminant? Is it the fact they all start by TextToSelect? Or they are all after a BR that follows DividerText, etc.. ?

Comment: @SimonMourier They are all after a BR that follows DividerText. 
But maybe i can simply remove <a> node and than replace 'DividerText' to Empty string. How can i get InnerHtml that excludes <a> tag?

Comment: It is not possible using Regex to return a subtree with elements removed. It would be possible though to return all text nodes of a subtree which are not inside an `<a/>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all texts that follow a BR after a DividerText like this (in a sample console app):

```
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.Load(MyTestHtm);

  foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[contains(., 'DividerText:')]/following-sibling::br/following-sibling::text()"))
  {
      Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
  }
```

Will dump this out:

```
TextToSelect1
TextToSelect2
TextToSelect3
TextToSelect4
```

The XPATH expression first gets recursively a text() node that contains a specific 'DividerText:' token, then get all following siblings BR elements, than gets all following sibling text elements.

Answer (score -1):

To select all text nodes following in the document:

```
//text()[contains(., 'DividerText:')]//following::text()
```

To select all sibling text nodes (following on the same level inside a wrapping element:

```
//text()[contains(., 'DividerText:')]//following-sibling::text()
```

---

If there is some text you need directly after, you would need XPath 2.0, this query also returns the part after the divider string, but needs the `substring-after` function that is not available in XPath 1.0:

```
//text()[contains(., 'DividerText:')]//(substring-after(., 'DividerText:'), following::text()/data())
```

If you're able to use XPath 2.0 or newer, there actually is an `substring-after` method:

```
substring-after(string-join(//text()), 'DividerText:')
```

You could also use `//text()` to fetch all text nodes and then use some `substring-after()` equivalent in C#, you might have to concatenate the resulting set/array.